# FATAL: Could not find component we just installed error

Tags: c#, com+

I have a 32 bit DLL in C# that I'm trying to register using regsvcs command (the one from .NET framework for 32 bit) on a 64 bit machine. The error that I get is:

`FATAL: Could not find component we just installed`

The TBL file is created, no registry entries are added and the component does not appear in Component Services.

If I try to register it using regsvcs command from .NET framework for 64 bit, I get that the DLL is in invalid format, error that make sense.

Is it possible to register a 32 bit component on a 64 bit machine?

If I compile the DLL as 64 bit and I register using regsvcs command for 64 bit, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred because of repeatedly register and unregister the DLL as 64 bit. Some classes remained uncompleted unregistered from registry and interfered with the 32 bit registration.

Searching and deleting all nodes that contained references to DLL classes from `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` solves the problem.

Comment: As a side solution for when the Component exist, the error "Could not find component" can be confusing. In these cases, deleting the component from Windows Component Services and re registering them could resolve the issue. Registering them might be in the post build events of your solution, if not, the following is an option, replacing the values in <>:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegSvcs.exe /appname:<Component name> c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\<Assembly name>\<Assembly folder>\<Assembly name>.dll